# Проблема в том,что не могу перезаписать массив в другой поменьше

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Текст ошибки:

> Debug Error!
>
> Program: ...s\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project2\x64\Debug\Project2.exe
>
> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#986) at 0x000002D77156B4C0.
>   CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

Проблема, как я понял, в функции `check` (предпоследняя) когда удаляю старый массив, такое задание делал не один раз(на перезапись массива) конкретно в этом кажеться чего-то не замечаю.

Конкретно эта функция убирает из массива все числа которые повторяются, все работает проверял без удаление, но в задании нужно скоротить массив.

```
#include <iostream> // библиотеки все есть(не смог вставить)
using namespace std;
void fill(int* ar, int);
void print(int* ar, int);
int* fillThird(int* ar, int* ar1, int* ar2, int*,int*);
void sortBubble(int* ar2, int);
int* unpair(int*ar2, int*,int choice);
int* check(int*ar2, int*);
int main() {
    system("color 0F");
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    int size,size1,size2, choice, plus = 0;
    cout  << "Number of elements array1: ";
    cin >> size;
    int* ar = new int [size];
    size1 = size;
    int* ar1 = new int[size1];
    fill(ar,size);
    fill(ar1, size);
    cout << endl << "Array1: ";
    print(ar, size);
    cout << endl<<"Array2: ";
    print(ar1, size1);
    size2 = size + size1;
    int* ar2 = new int[size2];
    fillThird(ar, ar1, ar2, &size, &size2);
    sortBubble(ar2, size2);
    sortBubble(ar2, size2);
    cout << endl << "Array3: ";
    print(ar2, size2);
    ar2 = check(ar2, &size2);



    ar2 = check(ar2, &size2);
    cout << endl;
    print(ar2, size2);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Непарнi - 1  ||  Парнi - 2\n";
    cin >> choice;
    ar2 = unpair(ar2, &size2,choice);
    print(ar2, size2);
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void fill(int* ar, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        *(ar + i) = rand() % 10;
    }
}
void print(int* ar, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << *(ar + i) << " ";
    }
}
int* fillThird(int* ar, int* ar1, int* ar2, int* size, int* size2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        *(ar2 + i)= *(ar + i);
    }
    for (int i = *size,k=0; i < *size2; i++,k++) {
        *(ar2 + i) = *(ar1 + k);
    }

    return ar2;
}
void sortBubble(int* ar2, int size2) {
    bool sotted;
    int tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) { 

        for (int j = size2 - 1; j > i; j--) {
            if (ar2[j - 1] > ar2[j]) { // Спадання або зростання
                tmp = ar2[j];
                ar2[j] = ar2[j - 1];
                ar2[j - 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int* check(int*ar2, int* size2) {
    int b;
    int size3 = *size2;
    int* ar1 = new int[size3];
    for (int l = 0; l < *(size2); l++) {
        if (*(ar2 + l) == *(ar2 + l + 1)) {
            size3--;
            b = l + 1;
            for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < *(size2)+1; i++, k++) {
                if (b == k) {
                    i--;
                }
                *(ar2 + i) = *(ar2 + k);
            }
        }
    }
    /*delete[]ar2;*/
    return ar1;
}
int* unpair(int*ar2, int*size2,int choice) {
    int* ar1 = new int[*(size2)];
    if (choice == 1) {
        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < *(size2); i++, k++, k++) {
            *(ar1 + i) = *(ar2 + k);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < *(size2); i++, k++, k++) {
            *(ar1 + i) = *(ar2 + k+1);
        }
    }
    *(size2) /= 2;
    delete[]ar2;
    return ar1;
}
```

Comment: Что не работает? Можно вопрос сформулировать? Ошибка? Какая? Неправильные значения? Какие? Читаемость кода : -200%. Почему нельзя работать с массивом как с массивом через оператор [] Сами то эту кашу из указателей читаете?

Comment: Я просто сейчас указатели учу, ошибка на этапе выполнения, сейчас напишу код ошибки

Comment: https://snag.gy/nGHkBR.jpg - ошибка

Comment: потому что тут выход за массив  _if (*(ar2 + l) == *(ar2 + l + 1))_             и тут скорей всего тоже   _for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < *(size2)+1; i++, k++) {_

Comment: Так ошибка выскакивает в строке /*delete[]ar2;*/ ?

Comment: Да, но она не закоментирована в оригинале

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызывается дважды, размер массива в функции меняется, а вот `size2` остается тот же. И кстати элементы массива может и сдвигаются, а вот размер массива тот же.

```
ar2 = check(ar2, &size2);
ar2 = check(ar2, &size2);
```

Выход за границы массива

```
if (*(ar2 + l) == *(ar2 + l + 1))
```

Конкретно про  `/*delete[]ar2;*/` ничего сказать не могу, собрал у себя похожий пример - работает. Поэтому оставь такой код:

```
int* check(int*ar2, int* size2) {       
    int* ar1 = new int[*size2];

    delete[]ar2;
    return ar1;
}
```

и проверь работоспособность, если работает, то проблема в алгоритме, если нет, то... отпиши.